# How can i do a Inner join with three tables?

Tags: sql, join

I'm using `inner join` to merge two tables, but i want to add more one

```
$query = ("SELECT * FROM user A INNER JOIN applications B ON A.user_id = B.user_id  WHERE mark = 1 ");
```

I'm joining the user and the applications tables.

I want to call another table called `templates`, and call the I`D_template`.

how can i do that?

Comment: Google Syntax for join, its a very basic concept in relational databases.

Comment: What did you tried so far? And what was the problem with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INNER JOIN` syntax is the same for *2, 3 or n tables* :

```
SELECT * 
FROM user A INNER JOIN applications B ON A.user_id = B.user_id  
            INNER JOIN templates T ON ?.? = T.?
WHERE mark = 1
```

You should just add `JOIN` clause with the table you need and add `ON` clause with the joining condition.